# Core data validation Fails in case of email

Tags: ios, regex, core-data, nsregularexpression

I have added validation for email in `Core Data Entity` like in fig:

[image]

However it fails to validate. The error is something like this:

```
NSValidationErrorValue=example@gmail.com, 
NSValidationErrorPredicate=SELF MATCHES 
    "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",
NSValidationErrorKey=email,
NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 1680.)}
```

Is something wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is a bit off.

Try this

```
NSString *email = @"example@gmail.com";
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:email];
```

Comment: I am using core data reg. Ex. Not using NSPredicate. Here is my code.

Bool isValid = [object validateValue:&name forKey:key error:&error];

It always fail to validate.